# Halloween Special: Glow in the dark food

Tags: baking, coloring

Halloween is just around the corner! Prepare to panic bake as many spooky sweets and tricky treats as you possibly can over the weekend!

I'm planning to bake a lemon tart, mainly because the filling is quite light and seems as though it would take colouring pretty well. Also because lemon tart is delicious and should never need justification.

**My question is:**
Is there anything that I can add to my filling that will make it glow in the dark?

The ingredient(s) must:

- Make it glow (obviously)
- Survive the baking process without breaking down into something that doesn't glow
- Not make the lemon tart taste offensive

I must mention, as every google search has failed to make this distinction: I am looking for solution that glows in the *dark*, **not** a solution that glows only when exposed to UV light, although one that does both would be acceptable.

Comment: Radium?   (I have no idea how it tastes, but there was no requirement that it not kill whoever eats it).  Of course, if it was something in a glaze afterwards, it doesn't need to be heat stable. I've heard the stuff in glow sticks is non-toxic, but you have to deal with the broken glass capsule.

Comment: Radium tastes terrible, allegedly :(

Comment: Makes your tongue all tingly too.

Comment: @Joe Perhaps non-lethal, but not non-toxic: https://illinoispoisoncenter.org/my-child-ate-glow-stick

Comment: @Erica : hmm ... "Toxicity Level:  Minimally toxic in a small amount such as a taste or a lick." ... " It is important to wash off the liquid as soon as possible after the glow stick leaks.  If the liquid sits on the skin for extended period, more serious skin injury can occur (such as blisters or chemical burns). "    Well, good thing there was no requirement for the people eating it to live and/or not have chemical burns.

Comment: But I'm still going to argue for whatever you find, it be in a glaze on top.  The filling is opaque, and only the surface is going to glow.  Sure, you might not get the cut edges to glow, but you'd have to charge up the cut with light before you turn off the lights to see it glow.  And then you need to put more of the possibly objectionable tasting ingredient so there's sufficient at any surface for it to glow. (this is why fluorescing tends to be superior for this sort of thing -- as soon as it's cut, it'll glow under UV ... but even for that I'd go with a glaze)

Comment: This isn't strictly within the requirements, but why not make the dessert as normal and then serve it in a light up cup?  https://www.amazon.com/Cups-4PCS-Batteries-VDS-Nightclub-Halloween/dp/B0722RWQ6F  I know it's not customary to serve cups of tart, but if you're going to push the envelope of what's normal, you may as well go all out.  You might even be able to find some glow-in-the-dark spoons to go with it.

Comment: As far as I know, things that glow in simple darkness need to be charged by placing them under light. I doubt that this technique is scientifically possible with anything edible. Even if it is, it might break down during the process of baking

Comment: "Glow in dark" is usually either radium, or Ca/Zn sulfide. Nothing food grade. Luminol is also not a food grade material: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminol Nor is Fluorescein. Looks likes people use vitamin B2: https://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/make-glowing-green-candy-0126098/ That's a fluorescent mix, not a glowing one. As far as I know, there are **no** food safe phosphorescent mixes, other than the spark you can achieve by cracking a mint in your mouth: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mint+spark&t=ffsb&ia=videos

Answer (score 2):

Use bioluminescence. Glow worms are edible and they are phosphorescent. You could make powder from organisms that have phosphorescence (glow worms). Crush them, sprinkle them on top of  [lollipops](https://blog.khymos.org/2009/02/11/the-flemish-primitives-glowing-lollipops-part-4/) or you could try crushing up GloFish:
https://www.foodprocessing-technology.com/features/featureglowing-sushi-experimenting-futuristic-food/  These will glow in a dark room, but only faintly. You can use blacklight to enhance the bioluminescent ingredients response.  Here's some nice pictures of fluorescent dye from glowing jellyfish for glow beer using a yeast that responds to "UV or blue light" according to gizmodo. No UV light needed.
 https://www.eater.com/2016/12/8/13886320/glow-in-the-dark-beer-jellyfish-genetic-engineering
Also check out the links at the bottom of that Eater article on glowing beer, glowing udon noodles, and glowing ice cream.

An alternative to food that glows on is own is to use the more commonly available neon colored dyes could look like they glow. These super-bright hues won't give off their own light for a true glow, but will reflect lots of ambient light.

Disney has done a lot of research on making glowing food and they've gone with the LEDs or light-sticks inserted into food. The effect is food safe and dependable, or else they wouldn't use it: [Disney's InfinityAide](http://www.cosmopolitan.com/food-cocktails/a9995474/disneyland-glow-lemonade/)  or [Fairy Floss](http://www.refinery29.com/2017/06/157376/disney-cotton-candy-glow-in-the-dark) or [LightSaber Churros](https://www.thedailymeal.com/news/travel/disneyland-s-new-lightsaber-churros-transform-you-jedi/051117?referrer=yahoo&category=beauty_food&include_utm=1&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=yahoo&utm_campaign=feed)  Perhaps bake your pie in two pieces and then drop a glowing light cube inside your lemon filling and then plop  on the pre-baked top? Or maybe make a crust that has holes in it that you can poke a few small lightsticks into.

The most common way to get a glow in the dark effect is to use UV (fluorescent dyes) because many food safe ingredients (such as tonic water and caramel) respond to UV wavelengths. The UV causes the ingredient to give off its own light (fluoresce). However, I'm not sure if the quinine from tonic water will survive baking. Lots of websites show people using tonic water on their cup/cakes after covering them with jello, like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTh4K9Jmh0g  There is [research](https://phys.org/news/2015-02-fluorescing-food-dyes-probes-quality.html) about them at Rutgers. Apparently these edible fluorescent food colors are routinely added to food or pharmaceuticals: Allura Red, Sunset Yellow, Brilliant Blue, Fast Green and Tartrazine, a yellow-colored dye. Read more about fluorescent food dyes at: https://phys.org/news/2015-02-fluorescing-food-dyes-probes-quality.html#jCp

Anyway, you could avoid UV and go for blue light. Some things that will flourescen under UV will respond to blue or purple LED light.

Comment: "I must mention, as every google search has failed to make this distinction: I am looking for solution that glows in the dark, **not** a solution that glows only when exposed to **UV light**, although one that does both would be acceptable."

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Neon-Purple-Green-4-pack-Color/dp/B004MNYB6U/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8  Maybe the illusion of glowing, combined with a light source (e.g. glow sticks or LEDs)?

Comment: The terms are "flourescent" vs "phosphorescent" ...

Comment: Quinine would plausibly survive baking (melting point is 177°C, and that won't be reached if it is dissolved in water which doesn't dry up during baking - and even melting doesn't necessarily mean the fluorescence will be broken, AFAIK). However, quinine is quite bitter, so flavor is affected (depending on quantity used, of course).

Comment: @gustafc chemically speaking the thermal stability of a compound and its melting point have nothing to do in common.